# Neo4j Custom Procedures: How to pass query parameters?

Tags: stored-procedures, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write a custom procedure for the Neo4J GraphDB in accordance to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/) and the there referenced [template](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template). The procedure should ultimately generate a graph projection using the GDSL, for nodes with a certain label that is provided as a procedure parameter. For this it is, of course, necessary to pass the label to the query that is to be executed within the custom procedure. However, I cannot seem to find out how to pass parameters to a query string.

```
    @Procedure(value = "custom.projectGraph")
    @Description("Generates a projection of the graph.")
    public Stream<ProRecord> projectGraph(@Name("graph") String graph) {

        Map<String, Object> params = Map.of (
            "graph", graph
        );

        return tx.execute("call gds.graph.project.cypher(\"$graph\", "
                + "\"MATCH (n:$graph) return id(n) as id\", "
                + "\"MATCH (src:$graph)-[]-(dst:$graph) "
                + "RETURN id(src) AS source, id(dst) AS target\") "
                + "YIELD graphName", params)
            .stream()
            .map(result -> (String) result.get("graphName"))
            .map(ProRecord::new);
    }

    public static final class ProRecord {
        public final String graphName;

        public ProRecord(String graphName) {
            this.graphName = graphName;
        }
    }
```

This code, unfortunately, does not work as intended, throwing the following exception:

```
Invalid input '$': expected an identifier
```

I did copy the syntax of prefixing placeholders with $-characters from other examples, as I could not find any hints on the passing of query parameters in the [JavaDoc](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/package-summary.html) of the library. Is this even the correct documentation for custom neo4j procedures? Am I possibly using the wrong method here to issue my queries? It'd be very kind if someone could lead me into the right direction on that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you use a string parameter the `$param` is automatically quoted, unlike the `String.format` for example.

Therefore there are 2 problems in your query:

- `\"$graph\"` : in this case you are doubly quoting the parameter, try to write only `$graph` instead
- Things like this `n:$graph` cannot be done unfortunately, the neo4j parameter handling is not able to recognize where to quote and where not, so you could use `String.format` or concat string with parameters (e.g. `"MATCH (n:" + $graph + ") return id(n)..."`).

So, in short, this piece of code should work in your case:

```
return tx.execute("call gds.graph.project.cypher($graph, " +
      "'MATCH (n:' + $graph + ') return id(n) as id', " +
      "'MATCH (src:' + $graph + ')-[]-(dst:' + $graph + ') RETURN id(src) AS source, id(dst) AS target') YIELD graphName", 
      params)
         .stream()
         .map(result -> (String) result.get("graphName"))
         .map(ProRecord::new);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed that did the trick and the query works flawlessly now. On a side note: I assume this operation could potentially lead to cypher injections, correct?

Comment: @LorenzH. Good point. I think it cannot be so dangerous because the procedure has mode=READ, so it doesn't allow write / schema operations. However, to be safer, you could put backticks on the labels, so instead of MATCH (n: '+ $ graph +') return you should write MATCH (n: `'+ $ graph +'`) return, in this way afaik it is possible to create attacks because all `$graph` parameter would be seen as the name of the label.

Comment: Thank you again! I will make sure to use back ticks. The application I am writing is only going to be executed locally anyway, so I am fairly sure that the input can be trusted.